# Client, editing dynamically the value of the dom elements such as <div><p>Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Are there relatively simple ways to implement this:

- I have a div element with position absolute
- I am doing double click on it
- Now focus is on this div, there is a caret appeared
- I am typing and value of this div is changing

Thanks!

Comment: You can use jquery plugin to edit in place: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708801/whats-the-best-edit-in-place-plugin-for-jquery

Comment: What u have tried? Because then only we will get to know what is "relatively simpler" way.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [**content editable**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/html/content_editable). Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jk5zn/. And if you are worried about browser coverage, do not worry: http://caniuse.com/#search=contented

Comment: Is it all-browser compatible?

Answer (score 0):

This calls inline editing, a simple search returned [this blog entry](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/17/10-interesting-inline-editor-plugins-you-might-be-searching-for/)

Answer (score 0):

For the case that you don't want to use jquery (or other frameworks for this)...

You almost written the algorithm by yourself!

When ondblclick event of the div fires, show pre-created textarea on the position of the div. 
When onblur event of that texarea fires, just pass the value of textarea to innerHTML of the div.

thats the magic.